# Customized drop down for top bar

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7

I'm looking for information about how to make a navigation bar with drop down functionality similar to the big iPad apps like on the picture below. It looks like they are using the same elements.

[image: http://imgur.com/FeDA6AH]

Is there some kind of support in iOS7 for this? Or any third-party implementation?

I've tried searching but I can't find anything that looks similar to the picture posted.

Comment: it is a pop over view

Comment: Whenever you need to check about the UI element, check [Apple's Mobile HIG](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/MobileHIG.pdf) first. Check the popover section in the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a popover, managed by a UIPopoverController